# Views / Controller Actions / Routes / Gobal.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, coming from a web forms background in the past year and I've started working with MVC 3 recently and have questions that seem to have no good answers (none that I can find at this point) and wanted to post them here.  Any help would be appreciated.  My questions focus solely on controllers, controller actions, views, and the global.asax.

1. I understand the relationship to views, controllers, and actions within controllers.  When it comes to creating a view though, does every action associated with a view that is created have to be registered in the global.asax?  Example:  When creating an empty project, the global.asax already creates a default route for the Home controller with an action of Index and id being optional.  So, if I create another view called "AboutUs" based on the Home controller, do I need to registered that in the global.asax as a part of the Home controller?
2. Is there a one-to-one relationship in terms of controller / action and registration in the global.asax for routes?  Can more than one controller action be added to the same statement separated by comma (like as in the using the example Home controller in the global.asax and then adding another action to the same statement or does a new statement need to be added outside of that?
3. Is there a "best practices" standard to use when creating controllers / views / routes?

I am asking these questions since I am converting a web forms site over to MVC 3 and not finding many good answers to my questions.  Looking forward to any and all responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No you don't need to register every view you create in Global.asax. The routing will take care of that as long as you follow conventions (i.e routing that is defined for you or one you define yourself should you take this path)
2. Not again. When you create new Action inside your controller, you typically will need to create a view for that action to render what it intended to do (ajax/json actions can serve as an exception to this rule). But again, you don't need to register anything in Global.asax those. As long as you follow the routing convention defined in that Global file.
3. I'd say it comes with experience with MVC. In general, every problem has its own solution, so its up to task at hand, rather than general approach. You can, however, start with the default defined for you by MVC 3: I.E. redefined routing and multiple controllers with multiple actions in each. Again, following conventions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Gu had a [great post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) about how MVC routing works on his blog, you should check it out!

There to be a matching pattern in the Global.asax for every route, but not necessarily an explicit match.  For your example, if you have a view called 'AboutUs', if you have a controller action named that it will just work due to the pattern matching:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

The row: `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` is the pattern that is being matched by the routing engine.  It says that any URL path that matches above will be sent to the correct view.  For your example if you were to follow the url:  `Home/AboutUs` then it would take you to the Home Controller, About us view, with no parameter.

Regarding your 2nd question, the controller that is selected is also part of the pattern.  If you added a second controller, called Contact, and then an action called email, then this url would still follow the same pattern:  `Contact/Email`, so you would not need to add an extra route.

Here are some other great blog posts about how MVC routing works, which will point you in the right direction.  One on [Asp.Net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs), [a blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/25/kiss-your-asp-net-mvc-routes.aspx), and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)